# Calculate an infinite continued fraction

Tags: special-functions, continued-fractions, closed-form

Is there a way to algebraically determine the closed form of any infinite continued fraction with a particular pattern? For example, how would you determine the value of $$b+\cfrac1{m+b+\cfrac1{2m+b+\cfrac1{3m+b+\cdots}}}$$?

---

**Edit (2013-03-31)**:

When $m=0$, simple algebraic manipulation leads to $b+\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2+4}}{4}$. The case where $m=2$ and $b=1$ is $\dfrac{e^2+1}{e^2-1}$, and I've found out through WolframAlpha that the case where $b=0$ is an expression related to the Bessel function: $\dfrac{I_1(\tfrac2m)}{I_0(\tfrac2m)}$. I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: What do you mean by closed form? What form do you want?

Comment: The $m$ increments linearly or as a multiple of $2$?

Comment: @Ethan: Closed form, represented in terms of finitely many elementary functions, not as a recursive expression.

Comment: @BackinaFlash: The $m$ increments linearly.

Comment: Continued fractions of this form tend to be related to hypergeometric functions. The best example I could find right now is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_continued_fraction#The_series_0F1_2 ... when $b=-1$ and $m=2$, you get $\tanh1-1 = -2/(1+e^2)$.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to solve the case where $b=1$ and $m=1$, if that's any help, but I also want a general method.

Comment: For the Bessel function case, see e.g. [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/69524); the reasoning is similar for general arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start from the [difference equation for the modified Bessel functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.29.E1):

$$Z_{n+1}(x)=-\frac{2n}{x}Z_n(x)+Z_{n-1}(x)$$

Let $x=\dfrac2{m}$:

$$Z_{n+1}\left(\frac2{m}\right)=-nm\,Z_n\left(\frac2{m}\right)+Z_{n-1}\left(\frac2{m}\right)$$

Divide both sides of the recurrence with $Z_n\left(\frac2{m}\right)$ and rearrange:

$$\frac{Z_n\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}{Z_{n-1}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}=\cfrac1{nm+\cfrac{Z_{n+1}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}{Z_n\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}}$$

Now, replace $n$ with $n+\frac{b}{m}$:

$$\frac{Z_{n+\tfrac{b}{m}}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}{Z_{n+\tfrac{b}{m}-1}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}=\cfrac1{nm+b+\cfrac{Z_{n+\tfrac{b}{m}+1}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}{Z_{n+\tfrac{b}{m}}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}}$$

One can do something similar for $\cfrac{Z_{n+\tfrac{b}{m}+1}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}{Z_{n+\tfrac{b}{m}}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}$; iterating this transformation yields the CF

$$\frac{Z_{n+\tfrac{b}{m}}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}{Z_{n+\tfrac{b}{m}-1}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}=\cfrac1{nm+b+\cfrac1{(n+1)m+b+\cfrac1{(n+2)m+b+\cdots}}}$$

Letting $n=1$, we have

$$\frac{Z_{\tfrac{b}{m}+1}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}{Z_{\tfrac{b}{m}}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}=\cfrac1{m+b+\cfrac1{2m+b+\cfrac1{3m+b+\cdots}}}$$

Now, $Z$ can either be $I$ (first kind) or $K$ (second kind) (or a linear combination of those two); we use a big gun to decide which of the two solutions of the modified Bessel recurrence should be taken, in the form of [Pincherle's theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=nPREsCQm_PYC&pg=PA402). Before using Pincherle's theorem, though, we have to make sure that the continued fraction we are dealing with is convergent; one could use, e.g. [Śleszyński–Pringsheim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Aleszy%C5%84ski%E2%80%93Pringsheim_theorem) to show that the continued fraction being considered is indeed well-defined.

Having shown the convergence, Pincherle says that $Z$ should be the so-called *minimal* solution of the modified Bessel recurrence. Roughly speaking, the minimal solution of a difference equation is the unique solution that "decays" as the index $n$ increases (all the other solutions, meanwhile, are termed *dominant* solutions).

The [asymptotics of $I$ and $K$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.i) show that $I$ is the minimal solution; thus Pincherle says that

$$\frac{I_{\tfrac{b}{m}+1}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}{I_{\tfrac{b}{m}}\left(\tfrac2{m}\right)}=\cfrac1{m+b+\cfrac1{2m+b+\cfrac1{3m+b+\cdots}}}$$

Your desired continued fraction is not too hard to obtain from this form.

(This solution is more or less an adaptation of the method presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69524) to more general arithmetic progressions.)

Answer (score 2):

Reference:

D. H. Lehmer, "Continued fractions containing arithmetic progressions",  *Scripta Mathematica* vol. 29, pp. 17-24

> **Theorem 1**:
>   $$
> b+\frac{1}{a+b\quad+}\quad\frac{1}{2a+b\quad+}\quad\frac{1}{3a+b\quad+}\quad\dots
> = \frac{I_{b/a-1}(2/a)}{I_{b/a}(2/a)}
> $$
>
> **Theorem 2**
>   $$
> b-\frac{1}{a+b\quad-}\quad\frac{1}{2a+b\quad-}\quad\frac{1}{3a+b\quad-}\quad\dots
> = \frac{J_{b/a-1}(2/a)}{J_{b/a}(2/a)}
> $$

and other results...