# Simplifying an infinite fraction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions, infinite-product, continued-fractions

I am unfamiliar with infinite fractions and are far more comfortable working with infinite sums, products, etc. Is there a way to convert this function which takes the form of an infinite fraction into an algebraic form or infinite sum/product so that it can be more easily evaluated?

$f\left( x \right) =x+\frac { 1 }{ 1+x+\frac { 1 }{ 2+x+\frac { 1 }{ 3+x+\frac { 1 }{ \ddots  }  }  }  } \\ $

Comment: Assuming convergence, $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{f(x+1)},$ for whatever it's worth.

Comment: @phdmba7of12 you cannot post graphics in comment section

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction#The_series_0F1

Comment: @phdmba7of12 already done [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28514/posting-a-graphic-in-comments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate an infinite continued fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342518/calculate-an-infinite-continued-fraction)