# Closed form expression for continued fraction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, continued-fractions

While I was trying to determine the value of the following infinite series:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}$$
I realized that it is equal to the value of the following continued fraction:
$$\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{3/2}{3+\cfrac{4/2}{4+\cdots}}}$$
I know that the value of <strike>$e-2$</strike> is given by:
$$\cfrac{2}{2+\cfrac{3}{3+\cfrac{4}{4+\cdots}}}$$
So, there is similarity between these two continued fractions but I don't know if I can use the continued fraction for $e-2$ to find closed form for continued fraction given above. Any hint is welcomed.

Comment: To help sell the pattern, you should replace the $1$ on top with $2/2$. :)

Comment: @Pedja I changed your expression $2-e$ to the correct $e-2$, since the second cfrac is clearly positive.

Comment: See the series in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/833920/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks to Pedja's insight, I realized that $\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}$ you discussed in the link can be expressed as the sum of TWO nice continued fractions. Kindly see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791520/4781

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think it is easier to go for the sum, i will show a sketch why:

The product gives:
$$
P_n=\prod_{k=1}^n (2k+1)^{-1} =\frac{2^n n!}{(2n+1)!}
$$

using $n! = \int_0^{\infty} t^n e^{-t}$ and the series expansion for $\sinh(x)$ we get (i  don't jusitfy exchange of integral and series, but it should be fine!) for the sum:

$$
S=\sum_{n \geq 0} P_n=\int_0^{\infty}dte^{-t}\frac{\sinh{\sqrt{2t}}}{\sqrt{2t}}
$$

writing $x^2=t$ we get some integrals which can be expressed as Error functions yielding

$$
S= \frac{\sqrt{e \pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$

@Claude rightfully pointed out that the sum in question (call it $s$) starts at $1$ so we have

$$
s=S-1
$$

which is also a very unexpected form for your partial fraction :)

Comment: The summation starts at $n=1$. So, you result is correct with a $\color{red}{-1}$ in front of it

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks, i updated my answer accordingly