# Expressing Ramanujan's $\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}$ as $two$ continued fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, continued-fractions, error-function

Due to a recent comment by Akiva about [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1542090/4781), I decided to revisit Ramanujan's beautiful continued fraction (plus series) relating $\pi$ and $e$,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}
=1+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\dots+\,\cfrac1{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\ddots}}}}$$

By sheer happenstance, I came across [Pedja's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4327258/4781) from 2021 and realized the series is also a ***nice*** continued fraction,

\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}
&=1+\cfrac{2/2}{2+\cfrac{3/2}{3+\cfrac{4/2}{4+\cfrac{5/2}{5+\ddots}}}} \; + \; \cfrac1{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\ddots}}}}\\[4pt]
&=1.41068613\dots  + 0.65567954\dots = 2.06636567\dots
\end{align}

where the decimal expansions are OEIS A060196, A108088, A059444, respectively. The first continued fraction does not appear in Mathworld's [Continued Fraction Constants](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstants.html), but the reciprocal of the second does and is labeled as $C_3 \approx 1/0.65567954 \approx 1.5251352.$

After a session with *Mathematica*, one can observe that Ramanujan's general form (Entry 43, "*Chapter 12 of Ramanujan's Second notebook: Continued fractions*") for this identity have addends that have closed-forms. Let,

$$A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \prod_{k=0}^n\frac{x^n}{2k+1} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e^x}{2x}} \operatorname{erf}\Big(\sqrt{\tfrac x 2}\Big)$$

$$B = \cfrac1{1+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{x+\ddots}}}} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e^x}{2x}} \left(1-\operatorname{erf}\Big(\sqrt{\tfrac x 2}\Big)\right)$$

with [*error function*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) $\operatorname{erf}(z).$ Therefore,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e^x}{2x}} = A+B$$

for $x>0$. The first identity was just the case $x=1$.

---

**Questions:**

1. For general $x>0$, can we express the series $A$ as a continued fraction similar to the one above?
2. Likewise, can we express the continued fraction $B$ as a series similar to $A$?

Comment: Nice problem (as usual !)

Comment: From browsing the comments from [other posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2090204/4781), we have the alternative form,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n\cdot\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,e^{z^2}}{2}\,\operatorname{erf}(z)$$
With a change of variables $z=\sqrt{\frac x 2},\,$ we recover Ramanujan's $A$,
$$A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!!} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e^x}{2x}}\,\operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac x 2}\right)$$
and the cfrac as the special case $x=1$.

Comment: This is great for sure

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It seems the story is not finished yet. There may be a _cubic_ counterpart to Ramanujan's identity in [this sequel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4792229/4781).