# Hint needed to figure out sum of the series $x + \frac{x^3}{1\cdot 3} + \frac{x^5}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}+...$

Tags: power-series, closed-form

$$x + \frac{x^3}{1\cdot 3} + \frac{x^5}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}+...$$
I was wondering how should I move ahead to try to figure out the sum of this series.
I will appreciate any hints.

Comment: What number is 1.3.5?

Comment: @PrinceM Likely the double factorial $$(5)!!=5\cdot 3\cdot 1$$ is what is intended.

Comment: Some places use a lowered dot $.$ instead of the centered dot $\cdot$ for multiplication.

Comment: Hint (assuming $a.b$ is $a \times b$). Differentiate the sum and see if you can manipulate the result algebraically to get the original power series back.

Comment: Is the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}j!\cdot 2^j$?

Comment: @canseeker, don't forget that when you are satisfied with an answer you are encouraged to [accept it](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: This is very famous. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/833920/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the series expansions for the [Error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html)

Comment: No, those have complete factorials in the denominators.

Comment: You are right. Errorfunctions a better hint?

Comment: Ok, so now this is where I say "Please see identity $(9-10)$ in the following link"

Comment: @SimpleArt Please don't condone such an answer, nor attempt to translate and edit it into a form the answerer probably doesn't understand (but has googled) and in doing so, essentially endorsing such actions. This is, and remains, a link only answer.  If you feel you must intervene for the sake of "Truth" (with a capital "T), then vote for the correct answer, not one that even the asker could have written.

Answer (score 15):

Note that $f'(x)=1+x·f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$, so that one gets the series expression as solution to this initial value problem.

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x^2/2}f(x))=e^{-x^2/2}\\~\\
e^{-x^2/2}f(x)-0=\int_0^xe^{-s^2/2}\,ds\\~\\
f(x)=\int_0^xe^{(x^2-s^2)/2}\,ds
$$

Comment: Wonderful argument. Note that this can also be expressed in the form $\frac {\sqrt{2 \pi}}{2} e^{x^2/2}erf(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})$