# If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}$ then prove that $f'(x)=1+xf(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Question** If $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}$
>   then prove that
>
> $f'(x)=1+xf(x)$

**Book's Question**

[image]

I can prove its radius of convergence is infinity

**Book's Answer**

[image]

**My Approach**

$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!!}$

Now I cannot prove $f'(x)=1+xf(x)$

Comment: What about that step do you not understand?  The $1$ comes from the term when $n=0$ and, in general, the $2n+1$ cancels with the denominator turning $2n+1$ to $2n-1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr but there is double factorial in the numerator

Comment: $(2n + 1)!! = (2n + 1) \cdot (2n - 1)!!$.

Comment: The function $f(x)$ in your question is interesting and related to the error function. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/833920/72031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- In your derivation, what happens to the $n=0$ term?  It is not a constant.  In particular, for $n=0$, the corresponding term in $f$ is $\frac{x}{1!!}=x$, so its derivative is $1$.
- Consider $\frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)!!}$.  Since the double factorial is
  $$(2n+1)!!=(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)\dots1,$$
  the first factor of the double factorial cancels, leaving $(2n-1)!!$.  Note that $!!$ does not mean taking the factorial twice.

Comment: Thank You Sir. This formula $$(2n+1)!!=(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)\dots1,$$ Cleared all my doubts

Comment: I did not know this before

Answer (score 1):

If you are given a power series
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n
$$
with positive (possibly infinite) radius of convergence, then in the interval of convergence
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}\tag{*}
$$
The shift in the starting index is done because $x^{n-1}$ would be wrong for $n=0$.

However, your series is not in the form (*), because it has no term for $x^0$, so we don't need to take care of it when differentiating term by term. Hence
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!!}
$$
Now we can only simplify
$$
\frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)!!}=\frac{1}{(2n-1)!!}
$$
when $n>0$, so we have to detach the initial term:
$$
f'(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!!}
=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n-1)!!}
=1+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!!}
$$
with the shift $n=k+1$ we finally get
$$
f'(x)=1+x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!!}
=1+xf(x)
$$

### *Caveat*

The definition of the *semifactorial* $m!!$ is
$$
m!!=
\begin{cases}
2\cdot 4\cdot \ldots \cdot m & \text{$m$ even} \\[4px]
1\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot m & \text{$m$ odd}
\end{cases}
$$