# $\sqrt{\frac{\pi e}{2}}=\frac{1}{1+\mathrm{K}_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{i}{1}}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n+1)!!}}$ implies $\sqrt{\pi e/2}\notin Q$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi, continued-fractions, rationality-testing

[On the OEIS Wiki](http://oeis.org/wiki/Sqrt(pi*e/2)) immediately after the formula
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi e}{2}}=\frac{1}{1+\mathrm{K}_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{i}{1}}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n+1)!!}}$$
(where I am using $\mathrm{K}$ as in the third notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Notation) for continued fractions)  it is written "Since it is not known whether $\pi e$  is irrational or not, it is thus not known whether  $\sqrt{\pi e/2}$   is transcendental or not (although it is obviously irrational)."

How can the irrationality of $\sqrt{\pi e/2}$ be derived from the formula?

Comment: What on earth does the big $K$ mean?……Oh.

Comment: I don't see why that would be obvious, and it would also imply that $\pi e$ is not of the form $\frac{2p^2}{q^2}$ for integer $p, q$.

Comment: I think this sum is due to Ramanujan, and there already is another question similar to this.

Comment: Perhaps this may be of use: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833920/an-infinite-series-plus-a-continued-fraction-by-ramanujan

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing obvious (from this particular expression, discounting the other things known about $\pi$ and $e$).

The continued fraction is general, so the fact that it doesn't terminate means nothing (unlike for simple continued fractions).

However, the series represents the [Engel expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion) of some number $x$. The Engel expansion of a real number is unique. It is also known that the expansion is finite (terminating) iff the number is rational.

Thus:

$$x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n+1)!!}}=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3 \cdot 5}+\frac{1}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}+\cdots$$

is irrational.

(In the same way, it is 'obvious' that $e$ is irrational, going by its Engel expansion, which is the same as one of its usual definitions as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$).

Of course, the fact that one part of the sum is irrational, doesn't mean that the whole sum is, since, in principle, the continued fraction could have the form $\frac{p}{q}-x$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$.